# Number theory: what does $f \ll_\epsilon k^{-2}$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, notation

I am reading a paper, http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.01870, that uses the notation $f \ll_\epsilon k^{-2}$. What does this mean? My best guess is $f = k^{-2 - o(1)}$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Where is it in the paper?

Comment: (my guess would by $f = \varphi(\varepsilon)\cdot k^{-2}$, where $\varphi(\varepsilon) \xrightarrow[\varepsilon\to 0]{}0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $f \ll_\epsilon g$ is the same as $f \in O_\epsilon(g)$, which is the same as saying that there exists some $X$ and some constant depending on $\epsilon$, which we'll denote by $C_\epsilon$, such that
$ \lvert f(x) \rvert < C_\epsilon g(x)$ for all $|x| > |X|$.

In this case, presumably $f$ depends in some way on $\epsilon$. You didn't mention where in the paper you have a question. But in the paper you mention, I notice occasions like equation $(3.3)$, where the left hand side is the expectation of a function $f$ over an event $E = E(\epsilon)$, depending on $\epsilon$. I didn't read the paper closely enough to parse exactly how the event depends on $\epsilon$, but that's how it's used.

Comment: The first appearance of the notation is at (3.3) in the paper. This seems right. Thank you.