# Precise meaning of $\ll_{n, \varepsilon}$ in number theory paper

Tags: number-theory, notation

Upon reading [this paper of Dietmann](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.5341.pdf), I came across the following line

> $N_n(H;G) \ll_{n, \varepsilon} H^{n - 1 + \delta_G + \varepsilon}$

that appears in the statement of Theorem $1$. What precisely does the symbol $\ll_{n, \varepsilon}$ mean in this context?

---

Dietmann does not explain what this notation means, and I have never seen this notation before.
The left hand side of this "inequality" does not depend on $\varepsilon$, contrary to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666285/number-theory-what-does-f-ll-epsilon-k-2-mean), but from reading the answer there my guess is

> For all $\varepsilon > 0,$ there exist constants $M, K > 0$ such that for all $n > M$, we have that $N_n(H;G) \leq K H^{n - 1 + \delta_G + \varepsilon}$.

After reading [this blog post of Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/the-probabilistic-heuristic-justification-of-the-abc-conjecture/) and looking at his statement of the ABC conjecture (which uses the notation $\ll_\varepsilon$), and looking at the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Formulations), which expresses the ABC conjecture in terms of quantifiers, I think that $N_n(H;G) \ll_{n, \varepsilon} H^{n - 1 + \delta_G + \varepsilon}$ could also mean

> For all integers $n \geq 1$, $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a constant $K$ such that $N_n(H;G) \leq K H^{n - 1 + \delta_G + \varepsilon}.$

Comment: $X \ll_{n,\epsilon} Y$ typically means that there's a "constant" $C$ **which depends on the parameters** $n$ and $\epsilon$ such that $X \leq C \cdot Y$.  This is meaningful when you consider $X$ and $Y$ as functions of some other variable besides $n$ and $\epsilon$, and treat $n$ and $\epsilon$ as parameters

Comment: @Adam I think this is the intended meaning. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X \ll_{n,\epsilon} Y$ typically means that there's a "constant" $C$ **which depends on the parameters** $n$ and $\epsilon$ such that $X \leq C \cdot Y$. This is meaningful when you consider $X$ and $Y$ as functions of some other variable besides $n$ and $\epsilon$, and treat $n$ and $\epsilon$ as parameters.